# How to correctly secure swagger with oauth in spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth, swagger

I have an application created using spring boot 2 with oauth2 implemented. I also use swagger. I wanted to secure access to swagger via oauth token (I use jwt tokens in the app). I have followed directions from [baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api#highlighter_461746) (point `7`). I've downloaded project they provided under the article.

1. I've run `AuthorizationServerApplication` on port `8081` (set by default by author)
2. Then I've run `ResourceServerApplication` (in `oauth-resource-server-2`) on port `8088` and context path `/spring-security-oauth-resource`
3. According to the article, I go to: `http://localhost:8088/spring-security-oauth-resource/swagger-ui.html`
4. What I get is `401` on `swagger-ui.html`
5. *my changes from now on* - I change from `.antMatchers("/swagger*", "/v2/**")` to `.antMatchers("/spring-security-oauth-resource/swagger*", "/spring-security-oauth-resource/v2/**")` and re-run `ResourceServerApplication`
6. One more time go to: `http://localhost:8088/spring-security-oauth-resource/swagger-ui.html` and indeed has `Authorize` button like on screenshot in the article but below that has the entire api:
7. [image: swagger api screenshot]

What am I doing wrong ? How it supposed to be handled ? what's the meaning in making `/v2/api-docs` as `permitAll()` when I want to secure it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, Swagger API is done to display all resources publicly and just authentic if someone has correct credentials.

Comment: so you mean that swagger resources are visible publicly ? but if you want to hit the API (by `try it out` -> `execute`) you need to authorize yourself first, by clicking `Authorize` button in swagger and obtain oauth token ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you want to use some endpoint on some resource, it's mandatory Authorize if you have some api key/api token according your project. Else you won't be able to access some resource.

Comment: I am here to learn only, so please be understanding, but isn't it a security breach ? How it works in production/real world ? is it accessible as well ? (asking about resources visibility, not making calls)

Comment: Okay let me explain on my experience, Swagger API was used just for testing  to any user can test it. If some user wants access to production then we provided domain and necessary  permissions which production shouldn't be published to real world, why? Because as they have Documentation swagger API so they can access easily because API is for developers only.

Comment: to sum-up. No swagger in production at all (as it is only for developers, and it wouldn't be safe). In development/test environment we have swagger available, it means that you can see all resources but need to provide credentials if you want to hit api (to dev/test rest controllers only). Did I get it right ?

Comment: Yes,  you got it.